# ShowMessagePos(msg,myform.left+x,myform.top+y)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I want to center a message on my form (FM, XE5). It works well in (FM, XE2):

The placement coordinates `(myform.left+x, myform.top+y)` are correct but the message is always placed in the center of the monitor that hosts the center of my form.

Here's the problem expressed in its easiest form:

```
ShowMessagePos('Hello',0,0) gets posted at screen center; as does 
ShowMessagePos('Hello',1700,0), as does
ShowMessagePos('Hello',1700,1100), as does
ShowMessagePos('Hello',0,1100).
```

So "ShowMessagePos"  acts the same as  "ShowMessage".

Comment: What are the `x` and `y` values ? How do you calculate them ? I'm asking because the [`ShowMessagePos`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Dialogs.ShowMessagePos) reference says, that the coordinates you're passing there should be the upper-left corner of the message box, so to center that message box you'd have to know its size before you show it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your actual code, so we can see what you're trying that isn't working for you.

Comment: X is about 1/2 "myform" width, Y is about 1/2 "myform" height.

Comment: 'about' means myform.left + 1/2 forms width (known) - 1/2 dialog's width (guessed).by.

Comment: ShowMessagePos(inttostr(SaeForm.Left)+'x'+inttostr(SaeForm.Top),0,0);

Answer (score 0):

```
function TForm1.ShowMessageCenter(const AOwner: TForm; const Msg: string):Integer;
begin
  with CreateMessageDialog(Msg, mtInformation, [mbOk]) do
    try
      Left := AOwner.Left + (AOwner.Width - Width) div 2;
      Top := AOwner.Top + (AOwner.Height - Height) div 2;
      Result := ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end
end;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).